# Ceiling Fan capacitor question

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am trying to replace my capactitor in my ceiling fan, because the blades do not  spin but I do hear a humming sound. When I opened it  up. I have 2 capacitors

The first capacitor is smaller and has 3 wires and is rated 4uf 250V
Red
White
White

The second capacitor has 3 wires and is rated 5uf 470 1/2W and 6uf 470 1/2W
Gray
Purple 
Brown

My question is I CANNOT find ANY matching capacitors online! Does anyone know what other kind of capacitor I can use?

[image]

[image]

EDIT: To clarify lets say I buy these two capacitors, how exactly would I wire this? I couldn't find matching capacitors online

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume these are for the speed control -see my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are speed control capacitors.

For clarification as another poster pointed out - one is for speed settings (4.5uf with resistors - aka RC network) the other 5uf is a run or start capacitor. 
The link below is a package with 3 capacitors built in - note it does not have the RC network for the speed control but has your 5uf - 250Volt you can use for the start/run capacitor, it might work to replace both of your units - there are others that have these 3 capacitors with 5 wires as well making it easier to install.

[Capacitor 4.5uf/5uf/6uf](https://www.e-musa.com/Sku/271905?cid=SHOP_Barnett_ALL_C&CATARGETID=120267650000038479&cadevice=c&gclid=CJKI-IGosdMCFdgOgQode_cMGQ)

[other Ceiling Fan Capacitors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0171G7DL4)

[image]

Comment: Well, one of them is :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The 5uf is probably a start capacitor - 5uf sounds like that - you should find it in the same place. The link had a triple capacitor - probably usable in the ops situation.either way he needs to use the right terminology to search it - Ceiling Fan Start Run Speed Capacitor or a combo of those terms..

Comment: Ok so if i would get this particular capacitor- I would match up the wire colors with purple to purple gray to gray brown to brown and red to red. But that leaves me with 2 white wires and a gray wire left over? I'm a little confused with the wiring? Do I also need to find a RC network capacitor?

Comment: @kozmo I added a diagram - although you have 6 wires - you really only have 5 connections. Two of your old wires actually connect in the same place. See the added diagram for more clarity - I hope that helps you. This should work - but the resistors are a timing / filtering - in other words they filter electrical noise. I have used this setup in mine with no problems - you might even find these capacitors at a Home Depot (about 3 months ago I picked mine up there).

Comment: @Ken: Thank you so much!!!! I appreciate all your help

Comment: I've lost track of which wires connect to which ports, besides L. The purple leg has a 5 uF instead of 6. I've currently got the front grey (closest to the camera), the purple, and the brown wire floating. Ideas?

Comment: @MrMas - First an FYI, anytime we disconnect wires we tag both sides with tape,just in case it is a while to get back to it. Like reinserting bolts/screws/nuts in/on-to a part we removed, so they stay correctly with the part. The Grey leads [CBB61] on the capacitor pictured in my drawing should be attached to the same Orange Nutted source of 1st picture grey, grey, white. I can not see where the purple and brown wire are connected originally, but you should have two locations remaining for where those wires go and it will not matter they are both 6uf capacitors.

Comment: @MrMas If you are not the original poster - you will need to make your own question with pictures of your own. As your wiring might be different.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the "470K" represents the resistors.  The caps are 4 and (6 parallel to 5) microFarad respectively.

The second package contains a filter consisting of 2  caps and  2 resistors.

In any case, start by tracking down "SK" company, or check out the link in the other answer.